# Best methods and having trouble overriding bootstrap css

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, media

I'm working with bootstrap and I am running into an issue where I had to hard code a style into a page to get a div to act correctly. When I create a selector externally it does not respond even with an html and body selector.

My code for mobile viewing overrides

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {

html body.index { padding-bottom: 0px; color: #000; background-img: none; }

html body object { display: none; }
body div.fuller { display: none; }
footer { display: none; }
body .melt { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: solid 5px #000; }
iframe { margin-left: 0px; width: 560px; }
html body .retro { width: 480px; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden; }
}
```

I created a some media overrides but one of them is not working correctly because of the inline style. Any ideas at to why it's not working when I add it to my .css file? Also, Is this the way you guys code for mobile devices? This is new to me and I am open to any and all ways to tackle it.

Any advice welcome.

http://galnova.com is my website

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen.css"   media="screen"   />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="handheld.css" media="handheld" />
```

or

```
@media handheld {

html body.index { padding-bottom: 0px; color: #000; background-img: none; }

html body object { display: none; }
body div.fuller { display: none; }
footer { display: none; }
body .melt { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: solid 5px #000; }
iframe { margin-left: 0px; width: 560px; }
html body .retro { width: 480px; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden; }
}
```

or

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { ... }
```

or

```
@media handheld and (min-width: 20em) { ... } /* WIDTH */
@media screen and (max-height: 700px) { ... } /* HEIGHT */
@media screen and (device-width: 800px) { ... } /* DEVICE-WIDTH */
@media screen and (device-height: 400px) { ... } /* DEVICE-HEIGHT */
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the .retro styling, there's a typo in your CSS

Line 1229 of gain.css you have

```
htmlbody .retro { width: 480px; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden; }
```

... space missing between html and body

Hope this helps!